# Symfony / Doctrine: add annotiation to Attribute defined in 'MappedSuperclass'

Tags: validation, symfony, doctrine, mappedsuperclass

*Edit:*
I learned, that there's an annotiation missing for my subclass ('here it's just an ID', thx to GreenLeaf).
My actual problem now is, that I don't know, how to override this, I can't get it to work.

---

*Original:*

I just migrated a Symfony 2.0 Application to Symfony 2.2 and get an 'invalid entities'-information in the dev-profiler, regarding an unidirectional one-to-many-association. When using the console with

```
php console doctrine:schema:validate
```

I receive 2 Messages:

```
* The association \Entity\Watched#reference refers to the inverse side field \Entity\Reference#id which is not defined as association.
* The association \Entity\Watched#reference refers to the inverse side field \Entity\Reference#id which does not exist.
```

I think, that this is wrong, because 'id' is defined in a superclass. The App stills runs fine on the old DB (created with Symfony 2.0).
This are my classes (simplified):

Code: Select all

```
/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
abstract class SuperclassAbstract {
   /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
   protected $id = "";

   // some fields more...
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="watched")
 */
class Watched extends SuperclassAbstract {
   /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Reference", inversedBy="id")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="reference_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
   protected $reference;

   // some fields more...
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="reference")
 */
class Reference extends SuperclassAbstract {
   // some fields more...
}
```

Comment: In the inversedBy, you are supposed to put a field that is defined as OneToMany.
Here, it is just an id, that's why it is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must not see doctrine as an relational DB.... thanks!

I add a list to Reference to handle the other side of the association.