# Symfony 2.2 white/blank screen in prod (another one)

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.2

I updated a few files on my server, remove the cache-dir and had to recognize, that I receive a white page, after refreshing I was able to login and then got a blank screen.
I tried this localhost and got the same. app_dev works well. Googleing around I fount this change in the app.php

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true); // >> before: new AppKernel('prod', false);
```

This helped, since I had removed the cache again. Warming the cache didn't help either:

```
php console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

I developed this app under Symfony 2.0 und updated it while developing. It was the first time I had this problem.
I just can find older threads for this problem, so it seems to me, that I may done a fault while migrating.

Any hint?

---

EDIT:
1. Log just says (yesterday):

> pushHandler.INFO: get:  [] []

But as I remember, it didn't log that every time. btw: I have no accelerator installed.

Comment: Anything from the logs? (`app/logs`)

Comment: can you check the line with "$kernel = new AppKernel) in your question. How does it actually look like at the moment? (before and current is the same in the question). It should be set to false to display errors.

Comment: Do you have the correct read/write permissions on the cache? Because the `php` user will be different from the webserver.

Comment: @jamie0726: Right, the comment was wrong. Are you sure, that false means displaying errors? false is no-debug!

Comment: @bart: I'm currently testing local, which means win ;-) But Cache works with app_dev (also on my server after 'fixing' it) and, as told, also with the changes in the app.php

Comment: Check your webserver's error log

Comment: @Thomas K: on localhost, there are one warning and one error (including their stack traces) referring the same issue:
Failed opening required '.../app/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies\__CG__jwatchBundleEntityReferenz.php' (include_path='.;D:\Development\xampp\php\PEAR') in ...\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\ProxyFactory.php on line 92
 >> So trying to warm up the cache was a good idea ;-)

Comment: I had to think some minutes about it: Proxies__CG__jwatchBundleEntityReferenz.php is remarkable, because that entity has warnings as I found out some days ago  and which I can't solve: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827368/symfony-doctrine-validation-with-mappedsuperclass-add-annotiation-to-id-in-subc